# Why pip can't install any packages on my pc?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, mingw-w64, msys

Every time I try installing a package using pip I get the same error

```
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=40.8.0
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting Cython>=3.0a11
        Using cached Cython-3.0.0a11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
      Collecting cffi>=1.12.3
        Using cached cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error

        python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
        exit code: 1

        [16 lines of output]
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
          File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
          File "C:\Users\amm25\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ygsg1v5y\cffi_f0b1a39fa2e94757852c83125193be0d\setup.py", line 126, in <module>
            if sys.platform == "win32" and uses_msvc():
          File "C:\Users\amm25\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ygsg1v5y\cffi_f0b1a39fa2e94757852c83125193be0d\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
            return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 224, in try_compile
            self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\config.py", line 129, in _compile
            self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 344, in compile
            self.initialize()
          File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
            raise DistutilsPlatformError(
        distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

I have tried `pip install setuptools==65.0.1` when I googled it (I had very few answers to such a problem then I got this message `Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages (65.6.3)` I had the same problem when installing opencv working in another project and it has been more of 2 weeks searching for a solution

Comment: There is an issue for that in the official pip repository: [#11258](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/11258)